# Sequence converging to supremum of a function

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A$ be some bounded set and $f:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be some upper bounded, continuous function. Since $f$ is bounded, we know that $M:=\sup_{x\in A}\; f(x)<\infty$ exists.
Why can we always find an increasing sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\;\subset A$ such that $f(a_n)$ converges to $M$?

Comment: **Hint :** By definition of $M$, for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists $x \in A$ such that $M-\varepsilon < f(x) \leq M$. Use this fact to construct $(a_n)$ by induction.

Comment: Thanks, now it is clear.